# ANOVA single subject experiment

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

We have modelised an animal model to examine the distribution of a specific drug administered in two forms (either iv or per os) and a with a specific dosage (0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8 ug for each administration form). We have calculated the concentration of the drug in a specific region of the model for each administration form and its corresponding dosage. We know from previous animal experiments, that adverse events occur at certain dosage for either two administration forms.

We want to test following hypotheses

- higher concentrations of the drug in this specific region are associated with the occurrence of adverse events
- in this specific region, different concentration of this drug are found for the two administration forms
- there is an interaction between the administration form and the dosage on the occurrence of adverse events

In the research group, we first wanted to use a t test and ANOVA but are confused as we have only one “subject” and our data are serially correlated and violate the assumption of independence of the observations.

Could you give us a hint on a possible statistical way to answer our hypotheses?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.