# Repeated Measures ANOVA: Correction for a single participant?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I've got approximately 366 values in each of three columns (*control*, **post-test1** and **post-test2**) which have been collected over three sequential years.

My research has suggested that a repeated measures ANOVA is being the best way to test whether **post-test1** and **post-test2** means are significantly smaller than the *control* - however! I'm interested in investigating the results of a single participant (!). Is there a way I can correct for using a single participant / perhaps a more suitable test I can use?

I noticed a similar question [ANOVA single subject experiment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209637/anova-single-subject-experiment) never received an answer, but thanks in advance for any help you might be able to give!

[image: Example of the data in each of the three groups]

Comment: Do you have data on the single participant? If yes, what do you want to test. If no, what do you want to predict?

Comment: Hi Bruce - Yes, have full data on this participant and a number of others (however am interested in within-participant analysis over between participant). I want to test whether post-test1 and post-test2 values are significantly lower than the control values.

Comment: For further information - I have added initial regression visualisations to show what the data looks like.